# Подскажите как можно сжать серии массива, состоящего из единиц и нулей по такому принципу: [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1] переобразовать в [4,6,4,]?

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм

Помогите понять, как можно сжать серии массива, состоящего из единиц и нулей по такому принципу: массив [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1] преобразуется в [4,6,4,]?

Comment: *массив [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1] преобразуется в [4,6,4,]?* Неоднозначное преобразование, ибо преобразованному соответствует и исходное [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]. Правильно будет так - [1,4,6,4]. Т.е. указать, с чего начинать.

Answer (score 2):

1. Ещё один массив и счётчик ставим на 1
2. Цикл по текущему начиная со второго элемента
3. Если текущий элемент равен предыдущему - счётчик +1, если нет - заносим в массив и счётчик ставим на 1

---

учитывайте, что в массиве может быть 0 элементов или 1.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, получилось!

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
var b = a.reduce((r,x,i,a) => ((x===a[i-1] ? ++r[r.length-1] : r.push(1)), r), [])
console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно перебирать массив, считая сколько раз повторяется элемент

Но мне было интересно сделать через регулярку. Если представить массив как последовательность подряд идущих символов, то можно сделать регулярку, что находит их:

```js
let arr = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1];
let text = arr.join('');
console.log(text);
let matches = text.matchAll(/(.)\1*/g);
let items = [];
for (m of matches) {
    items.push(m[0].length);
}
console.log(items);
```

**UPD.** По совету, **Qwertiy**. Можно упростить, используя функции `match` и `map`:

```js
let arr = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1];
let items = arr.join("").match(/(.)\1*/g).map(x => x.length);
console.log(items);
```

Comment: Сделал перебрав массив, но вы подкинули очень интересный способ, спасибо!

Comment: `matchAll` не нужен, можно обычный `match`. И вообще можно в одну строчку записать: `[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1].join("").match(/(.)\1*/g).map(x => x.length)`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

Императивный подход:

```js
const arr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]; // 4 6 4

function getCounts(arr) {
  let res = [1];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === arr[i + 1]) {
      res[res.length - 1]++;
    } else {
      res.push(1);
    }
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(getCounts(arr));
```

Функциональный подход:

```js
const arr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]; // 4 6 4
console.log(arr.reduce((a, c, i) => (c === arr[i + 1] ? a[a.length - 1]++ : a.push(1), a), [1]).slice(0, -1));
```